# UIView with round corner and white border

Tags: iphone

Due to `UIProgressHUD` need to access private api,
so I hope to construct an `UIView` with round corner and white border.
I know to make the corner round is:

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

But how to make the uiview has round corner and white border at the same time?

Welcome any comment

Thanks
interdev

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Using the same layer object:

```
view.layer.borderWidth = 1;
view.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
```

Answer (score 12):

**Sometimes corner radius with white border does not work properly**  so I use `UIBezierPath` and `CAShapeLayer`.

For make the corner radius

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath;
maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.imageView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
self.imageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

For make the border white

```
CAShapeLayer*   borderShape = [CAShapeLayer layer];
borderShape.frame = self.imageView.bounds;
borderShape.path = maskPath.CGPath;
borderShape.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
borderShape.fillColor = nil;
borderShape.lineWidth = 3;
[self.imageView.layer addSublayer:borderShape];
```

It will work. Hope this help

Comment: Using .cornerRadius, .borderWidth, and .borderColor along with .clipsToBounds seemed to give me an artifact around the imageView when I wanted a round image with a white border. This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: @Phan Van Linh how can i achieve only Bottom line.

Comment: @JatinVashisht sorry, I don't work with iOS for long time so I can not solve it. Hope you can find a solution

Answer (score 11):

There are border properties in the layer of the view as well: eg:

```
view.layer.borderWidth = 1;
view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: CALayer is part of Core Animation, not UIKit. Therefore, it takes a CGColor, not UIColor.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I was just typing that from my head.

Answer (score 8):

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
view.clipsToBounds = YES;
view.layer.borderWidth = 1;
view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 5):

code to get rounded corners and border

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
view.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
view.layer.borderWidth = 1;
view.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[view.layer setBorderWidth:2];

[view.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor]];
```